# C - read and store data file for further calculations

Tags: c

I normally use R, and have a lot of trouble understanding C.  I need to **read and store** a data file, shown below, so that I can perform calculations on the data.  These calculations depend on user-entered infomation. Here's the data that I'm trying to read in (called "Downloads/exchange.dat" in my code),

```
dollar   1.00
yen      0.0078
franc    0.20
mark     0.68
pound    1.96
```

Here's where I'm at so far.  This reads the first line of data only and also returns it, which is not what I want.  I need to read this entire file, store the exchange rates with their respective currencies, and be able to perform calculations on them later.

I think I need a `typedef`, perhaps? Later in the program, I ask the user for information like "Convert from?" and "convert to?".  In which case, they'll enter "mark", "yen", "dollar", etc. and I hope to match their response to the respective exchange rate (using the `string.h` library).

My code so far, to read in the data:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fpt;  // define a pointer to pre-defined structure type FILE
    char c;

    // open the data file for reading only
    if ((fpt = fopen("Downloads/exchange.dat", "r")) == NULL)
        printf("\nERROR - Cannot open the designated file\n");

    else   // read and display each character from the data file
        do
            putchar(c = getc(fpt));
        while (c != '\n');

    // close the data file
    fclose(fpt);
}
```

I feel like I need something similar, but completely different to read and store entire data file. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: is the length of your file fixed?

Comment: @chouaib yes, it will look like the above file, but sometimes with different exchange rate values.

Comment: So check my suggestion in the answer bellow

Comment: Ok.  Thanks. It will take me a little while to see if it works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a data structure to hold them and then a vector of this struct which will hold each currency read. You should make use of the [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) function that will not only save you from splitting values by hand but will also convert them for you. Here is something I came up with:

```
/* to store each currency you read */
struct currency {
  char name[256];
  double value;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  FILE * fp = fopen("x.dat", "r");
  int count = 0, i;
  struct currency currencies[30];

  /* this will read at most 30 currencies, and stop in case a
   * end of file is reached */
  while (count < 30 && !feof(fp)) {
    /* fscanf reads from fp and returns the amount of conversions it made */
    i = fscanf(fp, "%s %lf\n", currencies[count].name, &currencies[count].value);

    /* we expect 2 conversions to happen, if anything differs
     * this possibly means end of file. */
    if (i == 2) {
      /* for the fun, print the values */
      printf("got %s %lf\n", currencies[count].name, currencies[count].value);
      count++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To read them again, you'll need to iterate on the `currencies` array until you reach `count` iterations.

Since you already wants to match those values with the `strcmp` function, read the currency name, iterate on the array until you find a match and then perform calculations on those.

This is basic C knowledge and as much as I understand you're not used to using it, I strongly suggest you [read a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to find these answers in them.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks a lot.  Thanks for the link too.  I have a couple of books but they're crap and hence not on those lists.

Answer (score 0):

An example for writing:

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("c:\\test.bin", "wb");
char x[10]="ABCDEFGHIJ";
fwrite(x, sizeof(x[0]), sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]), fp);
```

(write declaration)

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size_of_elements, size_t number_of_elements, FILE *a_file);
```

If you were to read,

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size_of_elements, size_t number_of_elements, FILE *a_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you

- define a struct like :

`typedef struct{
   char currency[10];
   double rate;
 }rate_currency;`

- getline:

in your main function you use `getline` to read the file line by line :

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fpt)) != -1) ...
```

- Separate:

  use `strchr` to search for the `space character` to separate currency name from currency rate
- Insert :

declare an array of your previous struct :

`rate_currency arrOfStruct[10];`
then, insert one by one 
for example :

arrOfStruct[0].currency = "dollar"; //after you read it and separated it...
arrOfStruct[0].rate = 1.00;

- You're Done!

Comment: I advise against getline because it is a POSIX function and might not be available on other non-POSIX platforms.

Comment: +1 to your answer though I don't recommend complete answers, the OE must be left with a hint and some work to do, not only ctrl+c ctrl+v ;)