# While looping to end of file?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#define true 0

typedef struct
{
    char currency[8];
    int exchangerate;
} randT;


void main()
{
    int i, num;
    char currency1[8], ch;
    FILE *file = fopen("address", "r");

    randT name[7];

    while(fscanf(file, "%i", &name[i].exchangerate) != EOF)/*I think this is where my problem is*/
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s %i", &name[i].currency, &name[i].exchangerate);
        //printf("%s %i\n", currency1, num);
        //if (fscanf(file, "%i", &currency1) == EOF) break;
        printf("%s %i\n", name[i].currency, name[i].exchangerate);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

It is giving segmentation fault(core dumped) and i am fairly new to the fscanf functions and such. Please help!
my text file looks like this:
jeff 4
jina 5
jeffrey 6
jinna 7
jeffu 8
jinina 9
jeffz 10

Comment: Your seg fault is because you never initialize `i`.

Comment: Start by using `%d` instead of `%i` to read and print integers.  You also need to learn how to debug given a segmentation fault (hint, read up on gdb, and try `gdb a.out core`).  It will tell you which specific line went wrong.  And why is `name` of type `randT`?

Comment: This is funny, your question seems a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049510/c-read-and-store-data-file-for-further-calculations/24050061?noredirect=1#comment37080678_24050061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the crash is that you need to initialize `int i = 0;`. As you have it, `i` is indeterminate, so probably `name[i]` is a massively out-of-bounds access.

For the `fscanf`, you have mostly the right idea about the loop, except instead of checking `!= EOF` it's better to check  `== 1` or however many items you were reading.  If the file contains something that can't be processed as a number, then `fscanf` will not return `EOF`.

However this is not the right way to read your particular file. You read `%i` then `%s %i` every time around, but your file only contains a string and an int.  Change to:

```
while ( 2 == fscanf(file, "%7s %i", name[i].currency, &name[i].exchangerate) )
```

Also after doing `i++` you need to check that `i` has not gone out of bounds (i.e. it's less than `7`).

Note that `name[i].currency` decays to pointer to char - you shouldn't put `&` on it. Also you should use the length specifier to avoid running over the end of the array.

I would use the loop structure:

```
for (num_read = 0; num_read < sizeof name / sizeof name[0]; ++num_read)
{
     if ( 2 != fscanf(file,.....
         break;

     printf(....
}
```

Comment: can you explain why name[i].currency decays from pointer to char?

Comment: @user3580389 `name[i].currency` is an array and therefore a pointer. It does not decay to anything.

Comment: "Note that name[i].currency decays to pointer to char - you shouldn't put & on it."
Also, I tried "while ( 2 == fscanf(file, "%7s %i", name[i].currency, &name[i].exchangerate) )" and printing everything out but it seems to skip over some items?

Comment: In C, arrays have different behaviour to other variables. If you use an array when a value was expected then it decays to a pointer to the first element. So , despite the fact that `name[i].currency` is an array, the `fscanf` function sees a pointer to the first character of the array (which is exactly what it wants).

Comment: Also, I tried "while ( 2 == fscanf(file, "%7s %i", name[i].currency, &name[i].exchangerate) )" and printing everything out but it seems to skip over some items?

Comment: post your actual code, plus the input file, plus the output you are getting. (updating the question with the new stuff at the end might be best, or start a new question)