# Why am I getting stack smashing detected?

Tags: c, stack-smash

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char currency[80];
    double exchangerate;
} exchangeT;

void main()
{
    char from[10];
    int i;

    printf("convert from: ");
    scanf("%s", &from[10]); //this seems to be where the problem is
    //printf("into: ");
    //scanf("%s", to);
    //printf("How many of type %s", to);

    FILE *file = fopen("/home/jeffwang/Desktop/exchange.dat", "r");
    exchangeT exchange[5];


    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s %lf", &exchange[i].currency, &exchange[i].exchangerate);
        printf("%s %lf\n", exchange[i].currency, exchange[i].exchangerate);

        //if(strcmp (from[8], exchange[0].currency) == 0)
        //    printf("lel\n");

    }
}
```

this is the actual error message

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated

======= Backtrace: =========

/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x45)[0xb7700eb5]

/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x104e6a)[0xb7700e6a]
./a.out[0x8048622]

/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb76154d3]
./a.out[0x8048471]

======= Memory map: ========

08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 667062     /home/jeffwang/Desktop/ECS 30/a.out

08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 667062     /home/jeffwang/Desktop/ECS 30/a.out

0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 667062     /home/jeffwang/Desktop/ECS 30/a.out

09d8e000-09daf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]

b75cd000-b75e9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 918526     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

b75e9000-b75ea000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 918526     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

b75ea000-b75eb000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 918526     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

b75fb000-b75fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 

b75fc000-b77a0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 918505     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so

b77a0000-b77a2000 r--p 001a4000 08:01 918505     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so

b77a2000-b77a3000 rw-p 001a6000 08:01 918505     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so

b77a3000-b77a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 

b77b2000-b77b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 

b77b8000-b77b9000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]

b77b9000-b77d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 918485     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so

b77d9000-b77da000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 918485     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so

b77da000-b77db000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 918485     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so

bfd29000-bfd4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]

Aborted (core dumped)
```

What I don't understand is: I'm using user input as from[10] and I never exceed 10. Also, if I remove the pointer & in scanf, the error message does not come up. Also, when I change from[10] to something smaller say from[2], the error does not occur either! Wut?!

Comment: I think `&from[10]` is pointing to the end of the buffer, and you want simply `&from`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Technically, `&from` has the wrong type and is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Blorgbeard And `&from[10]` is pointing one-**past** the end of buffer, which is good for eval-of-address only, not dereferencing (which `scanf()` is obviously doing).

Comment: What is wrong with this homework ? I've seen same example 3 hours ago!! you'd better asked your question as a [comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049510/c-read-and-store-data-file-for-further-calculations?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely wrong.

```
char from[10];
scanf("%s", &from[10]);
```

The expression `&from[10]` is the address of the end of the array.  Not the last element, but the element "past" the last element, a non-existent element.  Use this instead:

```
scanf("%s", from); // Still wrong
```

Note that this is also bad, because you could get more than 10 characters written to `from`.

```
scanf("%10s", from); // Correct
```

Comment: @nodakai "someone like you" is a bit harsh, especially when comparing a two-line example to a widely used crypto library, don't you think?